# Patching Binaries For Android

Tags: android, binary, md5sum

I found an article about Patching binaries for iOS 
[Securing iOS Apps - Patching binaries](http://applidium.com/en/news/securing_ios_apps_patching_binaries/)
This method just have to go through the load commands of the Mach-O structure, find the assembly section (i.e the __text section of the __TEXT segment), and compute a cryptographic hash of the binary data.
I think I can apply it to Android if I can find the entry point of Android application.
My question: Do we have any way to get the "main" point address?

Comment: You want NativeActivity? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html  I think "__TEXT" seg is not for java...

Comment: Yes, thanks for your suggest. I find a way to do the similar hashing with my shared lib (*.so). I'm using elf header to read it and try to hash the memory of its section headers.